# Multidimensional Array Looping with Some Values Not Set - PHP

Tags: php

Anyone know how to do this?

I'm trying to loop through an array where not every object has a value. What I'd like to get is an array where the key holds the number that specifies the stdClass Object and has "value" as value. If there is no "value" specified "0" should be printed.

So the final array should look something like this:

```
Array ( 
[123456789_123456789] => 192 
[54321_98765] => 0 
[987654321_123456789] => 1292
[987854321_123456734] => 0
)
```

Here is the original output:

```
stdClass Object ( 
[123456789_123456789] => stdClass Object ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 123456789_123456789/insights/name_of_metric/period 
        [name] => name_of_metric
        [period] => lifetime 
        [values] => 
            Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [value] => 1292 ) 
                ) 
        [title] => Lifetime Post Organic Reach 
        [description] => A Description ... 
        [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
        [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
 ) )

[54321_98765] => stdClass Object ( 
    [data] => Array ( 

        [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
        [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
))

[987654321_123456789] => stdClass Object ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [id] => 987654321_123456789/insights/name_of_metric/period 
        [name] => name_of_metric
        [period] => lifetime 
        [values] => 
            Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                [value] => 1292 ) 
                ) 
        [title] => Lifetime Post Organic Reach 
        [description] => A Description ... 
        [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
        [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
))

[987854321_123456734] => stdClass Object ( 
    [data] => Array ( 

        [paging] => stdClass Object ( 
        [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
        [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/ALINK
))
)
```

This is what I tried so far:

```
    $aVar = array();
    foreach ($var as $var_1){ 
       foreach ($var_1->data as $var_2 ){ 
          foreach ($var_2->values as $var_3){ 
    $aVar[] = $var_3->value; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I believe I have to use `foreach (var_1->data as $var_2 => $var2_1)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? And into which concrete problem did you run while doing so? What hinders you to just check for that value for example?

Comment: Do you need the logic for the loop? To omit empty objects just use is_null or is_set and set the value to 0 if it is null, otherwise copy the value.

Comment: What do you have so far, what does your loop look like?

Comment: Hi @Hhrkre, I believe my biggest problem is being a PHP newbie ;) This is what I tried: $aVar = array();
foreach ($var as $var_1){
 foreach ($var_1->data as $var_2 ){
  foreach ($var_2->values as $var_3){

 $aVar[] = $var_3->value;


  }
 }
} 
I believe I have to use foreach (var_1->data as $var_2 => $var2_1)

but I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @G.W. That chunk of code belongs into your question. That will make it more readable as well.

Comment: Hi @hakre, just edited the question. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **isset()** "language construct" and **is_array()** function are your friend in this scenario, unless you are having another problem not specified, your problem is not very clear ;)

What you need to do is change your outer for-each loop to something similar to the following, with additional validation within:

```
$aVar = array();
foreach ($var as $object_key=>$var_1)
{ 
    if(isset($var_1->data) && is_array($var_1->data))
    {
        foreach ($var_1->data as $var_2 )
        { 
            if(isset($var_2->values) && is_array($var_2->values))
            {
                foreach ($var_2->values as $var_3)
                { 
                    $aVar[$object_key] = $var_3->value; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is untested, I don't believe I have made any syntactical errors.

Comment: Just nitpicking: `isset` is not a function but a language construct. ;)

Comment: It does not beg, see the [note](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php#refsect1-function.isset-notes) ;) - as said just informative.

Comment: It's still interpreted at runtime, is it not?